# Problemas con ordenamiento burbuja en c++

Tags: c++

Quiro ordenar una estructura llamada Estudiante de mayor a menor pero por promedio de notas, donde las notas se guardan en otra estructura llamada Evaluaciones.

El error que me da es el siguiente: cuando ingreso todos los datos para realizar el ordenamiento no me muestra el listado ordenado o me muestra los datos repetidos y los promedios mal almacenado y repetidos.

Ademas de darme un error a la hora de almacenar la posicion del `aux = listaAuxiliar[j]` diciendome que no esta declarado o que no se pueden igualar los tipos de datos, por eso que solo mando almacenar la posicion de `j` solamente, algo q no es muy normal en el uso de este metodo de ordenamiento.
Saludos de antemano.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct Evaluaciones
{
    float ES; //Evaluaciones Sistematicas
    float TCP; //Evaluaciones Trabajo Control Parcial
    float NF;//Evaluaciones Nota Final
    float PromNotas; //prome de las tres notas ES+TCP+NF/3
};
struct Estudiante
{
    string nombre;
    char ci[11];
    int edad;
    char sexo[10];

    struct Evaluaciones eval;
    int ausencia;
    bool aprobado;      //Para evaluar que esta aprobado por el promedio general de las notas.
    bool susPorConcp;   //Para evaluar que esta suspenso por concepto de asistencia.
} Estudiantes[30];

struct EstudianteAux
{
    string nombre;
    float PromNotas;
} listaAuxiliar[30];

void menu(); //declaracion de menu antes del iniciar
int choose;  //variable para almacenar la opcion para el menu

int main ()
{
    int matricula, aprob=0, susp=0, notaMin=3, posMayAus = 0, cantAus = 0, posMEA = 0, notaMEA = 0, posMenEA = 0, notaMenEA = 999999, nochoose;
    float promedio;

    cout<<"Digite la matricula del grupo: ";
    cin>>matricula;

    for (int i = 0; i < matricula; i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        cout<<i+1<<". Digite el Nombre del estudiante: ";
        getline(cin,Estudiantes[i].nombre);

        cout<<"\n. :Evaluaciones del estudiante: "<<Estudiantes[i].nombre<<".\n";
        cout<<i+1<<". Digite la evaluacion semipresencial: ";
        cin>>Estudiantes[i].eval.ES;

        cout<<i+1<<". Digite el resultado del TCP: ";
        cin>>Estudiantes[i].eval.TCP;

        cout<<i+1<<". Digite la nota final: ";
        cin>>Estudiantes[i].eval.NF;


        float TSum = 0;
        TSum = (Estudiantes[i].eval.ES + Estudiantes[i].eval.TCP + Estudiantes[i].eval.NF) / 3;

        Estudiantes[i].eval.PromNotas = TSum;

        system("pause");
    }
    begin:
    do
    {
        menu();
        switch(choose)
        {
        /*
            aqui van los otros casos de eleccion, todos bien, no los agregue para especificar el caso 6.
        */
        case 6:
        {
            //lista auxiliar de estudiantes

            for(int i = 0; i < matricula; i++)
            {
                //listaAuxiliar[i] = Estudiante[i];
                fflush(stdin);
                listaAuxiliar[matricula].nombre = Estudiantes[i].nombre;
                listaAuxiliar[matricula].PromNotas = Estudiantes[i].eval.PromNotas;
            }

            int i, j,aux;

            for(i = 0; i < matricula-1; i++)
            {
                for(j = i+1; j < matricula; j++)
                {
                    if(listaAuxiliar[j].PromNotas < listaAuxiliar[i].PromNotas )
                    {
                        aux = j;
                        listaAuxiliar[j] = listaAuxiliar[i];
                        listaAuxiliar[i] = listaAuxiliar[aux];
                    }
                }
            }

            for(i=0; i < matricula; i++)
            {
                cout<<"|-Nombre: "<<listaAuxiliar[i].nombre<<"-||-Promedio de Notas: "<<listaAuxiliar[i].PromNotas<<endl;
            }
            system("pause");
            goto begin;
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            cout<<"Disculpe, pero la opcion que solicita no esta disponible."<<endl;
            cout<<"Por favor, intente con uno de estos digitos >'1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9'<"<<endl;
            cout<<"Y le aseguramos que funciona. Gracias\a"<<endl;
            // system("pause && cls");
            goto begin;
            break;
        }
        }
        nochoose = choose;
    }
    while(nochoose!=9);
}
void menu()
{
    choose = 0;
    system("color 0f");
    cout<<"**************************************************"<<endl;
    cout<<"|Programa para controlar las notas de estudiantes|"<<endl;
    cout<<"**************************************************"<<endl;
    cout<<"---------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Siga las intrucciones en pantalla"<<endl;
    cout<<"=================================="<<endl;
    cout<<"1- Lista de estudiantes Limpios(aprobados y con menos del 20% de inasistencia)."<<endl; //ok
    cout<<"2- Estudiante con mas ausencias."<<endl; //ok
    cout<<"3- Promedio de ausencias y notas general del grupo."<<endl; //ok
    cout<<"4- Listado de los estudiantes suspensos por concepto de ausencias."<<endl; //ok
    cout<<"5- Listado de los estudiantes suspensos por concepto de notas."<<endl; //ok
    cout<<"6- Listado total de estudiantes, ordenado por promedio."<<endl; //usando burbuja
    cout<<"7- Mejor estudiante academicamente."<<endl; //ok
    cout<<"8- Peor estudiante academicamente. "<<endl; //ok
    cout<<"9- Salir."<<endl;
    cout<<"==================================="<<endl;
    cout<<"Seleccione una opcion :> ";
    cin>>choose;
}
```

Comment: Tu código, **no compila**, luego dificilmente puedes ver si ordena correctamente o no. O nos estás intentando engañar para que te hagamos los deberes o te has confundido al copiar... quiero creer que es lo segundo. Te sugiero editar la pregunta y arreglar el código para que, al menos, compile

Comment: ya listo, acabo de arreglar lo que me faltaba, ahora si compila.

Comment: y sigue dando el mismo problema con el ordenamiento..pudieras revisarlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Esto es C++**

No estamos programando en C,`struct` solo es necesario usarlo **al declarar estructuras**, no al declarar variables:

```
struct Estudiante
{
    string nombre;
    char ci[11];
    int edad;
    char sexo[10];
    /* struct */ Evaluaciones eval; // <<----
    int ausencia;
    bool aprobado;      //Para evaluar que esta aprobado por el promedio general de las notas.
    bool susPorConcp;   //Para evaluar que esta suspenso por concepto de asistencia.
} Estudiantes[30];
```

**No mezcles streams**.

Estás usando `cin` y `cout`... por lo tanto no uses `stdin`. Por defecto las dos entradas estándar (`cin` y `stdin`) están sincronizadas por motivos de compatibilidad... pero eso no tiene por qué ser así siempre. Si no están sincronizadas tu programa va a funcionar de cualquier manera así que te sugiero no mezclar sus usos. O usas `cin` o `stdin`, pero no ambos.

**No uses `fflush` con `stdin`**.

La documentación lo dice bien claro. `fflush` sirve para dispositivos **de salida**. En el caso de los de entrada el comportamiento es indeterminado, es decir, puede funcionar en algunos casos pero no está garantizado.

Para limpiar el buffer de entrada, aprovechando que estás en C++, puedes hacer esto:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
```

O, si como es tu caso la idea es que convivan `cin` con `getline`:

```
    cin.ignore(1);
    cout<<i+1<<". Digite el Nombre del estudiante: ";
    getline(cin,Estudiantes[i].nombre);
    cout << Estudiantes[i].nombre;
```

Esa línea elimina el salto de línea de `cin`, luego la siguiente llamada a `getline` funcionará correctamente.

**Tu algoritmo de ordenación**

```
for(i = 0; i < matricula-1; i++)
{
    for(j = i+1; j < matricula; j++)
    {
        if(listaAuxiliar[j].PromNotas < listaAuxiliar[i].PromNotas )
        {
            aux = j;
            listaAuxiliar[j] = listaAuxiliar[i];
            listaAuxiliar[i] = listaAuxiliar[aux];
        }
    }
}
```

El problema está en `aux=j`. ¿Por qué? Pues básicamente porque eso no está copiando los datos de ningún estudiante sino un triste entero, luego al ejecutarse la siguiente línea los datos que había en `listaAuxiliar[j]` se han perdido irremediablemente.

Prueba así:

```
EstudianteAux aux = listaAuxiliar[j];
listaAuxiliar[j] = listaAuxiliar[i];
listaAuxiliar[i] = aux;
```

**Reduce la vida de las variables**

No tiene sentido reutilizar variables cuando se usan para cosas diferentes. Crear variables, sobretodo si son de tipos nativos, es gratis, no consume tiempo de ejecución... y reduce el número de posibles errores en el código

Es preferible esto:

```
for( int i = 0; i< ...
  for( int j = i+i; j < ...
```

A esto

```
int i, j;
for( i = 0; i< ...
  for( j = i+1; j < ...
```

Ya que fuera de esos bucles las variables no existirán y, por tanto, no te molestarán. Es como tener los libros de matemáticas, física, historia, ciencias naturales, inglés y toda la librería de tu casa encima de la mesa mientras estudias gramática.

Por cierto, desde C99 (estándar que data de 1999) también es posible hacer esto en C, ahí lo dejo.

**Prohibido usar `goto`**

Si estás en programando en ensamblador, pase, pero por lo que más quieras. No uses `goto` en C++. No es necesario en absoluto.

**Cuidado con las copias**

```
for(int i = 0; i < matricula; i++)
{
    listaAuxiliar[matricula].nombre = Estudiantes[i].nombre;
    listaAuxiliar[matricula].PromNotas = Estudiantes[i].eval.PromNotas;
}
```

Este bucle estaría genial que funcionase correctamente... para que lo haga solo hay que reemplazar `matricula`  por `i` dentro del bucle:

```
for(int i = 0; i < matricula; i++)
{
    listaAuxiliar[i].nombre = Estudiantes[i].nombre;
    listaAuxiliar[i].PromNotas = Estudiantes[i].eval.PromNotas;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por todas las recomendaciones dadas, en verdad hacia bastante tiempo que no tocaba estos terminos y tambien mi base no fue tan buena como en otros lenguages. Ya ordena todo sin problema, esto: EstudianteAux aux = listaAuxiliar[j]; soluciono mi problema como tal. Gracias Eferion.